# What is the difference in Marshaling between Windows and Linux for .NET Core?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, marshalling

I'm trying to migrate existing library to .NET Core to be able to run it under Linux.

When using the library in Linux, the runtime throws System.ArgumentException:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in ConsoleApp6.dll: 'Type 'ConsoleApp6.MyStruct' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.'
>
> Stack trace:
>      at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.OffsetOfHelper(IRuntimeFieldInfo f)
>     at ConsoleApp6.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\user\source\repos\ConsoleApp6\ConsoleApp6\Program.cs:line 10

In Windows, it works as expected.
Here a simple Console app that demonstrates the issue:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((Int32) Marshal.OffsetOf<MyStruct>("buffer"));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct MyStruct
    {

        public Int16 number;

        public byte[] buffer;
    }
}
```

Here is the csproj file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.7.12" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I expect the output to be `4` in Windows and Linux, but in Linux it throws the above exception.

Comment: Have you tried it in .NET Core 3 yet?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Thanks for the suggestion. Just updated to .NET Core 3 but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core, you can't use `OffsetOf<T>`, [per the Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal?view=netcore-2.2):

> `OffsetOf(Type, String)`
> Returns the field offset of the unmanaged form of the managed class.
>
> `OffsetOf<T>(String)`  
> [Supported in the .NET Framework 4.5.1 and later versions]
>
> Returns the field offset of the unmanaged form of a specified managed class.

In order for your code to work on Linux, you'll need to use the `OffsetOf(Type, String)` overload instead.

```
Console.WriteLine((Int32) Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(MyStruct),"buffer"));
```

I've dug deeper into the [CLR source code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/ab2f9caaf35c96d029b96aa171ee65d04253cf7c/src/vm/methodtable.h#L2782); and there's no apparent reason why your code shouldn't work on Linux. The defining characteristic of it being `Marshalable`, that I can see, is whether or not it's an Interface.

I'm going to dig deeper -- I see source code in the `vm` folder; but I'd also expect to see implmentation source code for each target environment, and I don't see that.

Comment: offsetOf(Type, String) is obsolete: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.offsetof?view=netcore-2.2#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_OffsetOf_System_Type_System_String_

Comment: @khyal2008 It may be, but it's still in use by the .NET Core Framework: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/search?q=OffsetOf%5C%28&unscoped_q=OffsetOf%5C%28

Comment: I'm going to have to dig deeper on this failure; as the source code just calls the one I listed above anyway: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/d58a51f911efb3c98beca21b6cf08cc703424fdf/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Runtime/InteropServices/Marshal.cs#L177

Comment: my current work around is changing the buffer type from byte[] to IntPtr, but I really want to know why the original struct cannot be marshaled when running in Linux. I would appreciate to know what you come up with!